# Questions about stored procedure to update row with total value of rows deleted

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to delete rows from a `Transactions` table (which has a foreign key to my `Customers` table), and then update `Customers.StartingBalance` to reflect the sum of the deleted amounts.

So I have created a stored procedure. Here's what I have so far.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @CustomerBalances TABLE
(
    CustomerId INT,
    Amount BIGINT
);

-- Note: Caller has already begun a transaction

DELETE Transactions WITH (TABLOCK)
OUTPUT deleted.CustomerId, deleted.TotalAmount INTO @CustomerBalances
WHERE [TimeStamp] < @ArchiveDateTime;
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @CustomerBalances)
BEGIN
    UPDATE Customers  WITH (TABLOCK)
    SET StartingBalance = StartingBalance +
        (SELECT SUM(Amount) FROM @CustomerBalances cb WHERE Id = cb.CustomerId)
END;
DELETE FROM @CustomerBalances
```

Since SQL is not my core competency, I'm trying to understand this query better. In particular, I have some questions about the `UPDATE` statement above.

1. This will update all `Customers` because I have no `WHERE` clause, right?
2. This correctly handles cases where a customer has more than one matching row in the `@CustomerBalances` table, right?
3. Is the `EXISTS` clause needed here?
4. Will `SUM()` return 0 or `NULL` if there are no matching rows?
5. Does everything get cleaned up if I don't have the final `DELETE` statement?
6. It is critical that no changes are made to the `Transactions` or `Customers` table while I'm doing this. Does my use of `TABLOCK` make sense here?
7. Any suggestions about the overall approach I'm taking?

Comment: Is this microsoft sql server t-sql?

Comment: @DanielButler: Both. It's SQL Server (see the tags).

Comment: Storing what appears to be an aggregated value seems like a foolhardy idea, in my view. If you do need an aggregated value, why aren't you simply using `SUM` in the `SELECT` instead? Then you don't need to go back and update the values for the customer balances, and the value is derived from existing data.

Comment: @Larnu: Look closer. It is reflecting the total of the deleted values. Since you can't `SUM()` values that have been deleted, and the true balance must be maintained, a starting balance column is needed.

Comment: That doesn't change my point, @JonathanWood. if the total sum of a bunch of rows is 700, and you delete some rows with a sum of 400, the sum isn't still 700, it's 300. There's no reason to store the aggregate value.

Comment: @Larnu: Huh? Have you never used QuickBooks? You might want to archive old transactions. But this should *never* change your current balance? There has to be a way to know the starting balance. In your example, archiving old transactions must not change the balance, and so the new balance would still be 700. That should be obvious from looking at my code. Anyway, there's no debate about it. I need a `StartingBalance` column for each customer.

Comment: *"Have you never used QuickBooks?"* No. Why would I have? If the application is pertinent to the software, however, then you should tag it. You didn't mention that this is an archiving process either. EVen so, deleting the transactions seems like an odd choice. Why would you want to delete previous financial information?

Comment: @Larnu: The question has nothing to do with QuickBooks. If you look at the code, you can see it refers to `@ArchiveDateTime`. And, in Najinsky's answer, you can see he caught on to this being about archiving. But I didn't mention it because it had nothing to do with the question I was asking and I wanted to keep it as simple as I could.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. This will update all Customers because I have no WHERE clause, right?

Yes. Consider adding a WHERE clause such as:

```
WHERE Id IN (SELECT DISTINCT CustomerId FROM @CustomerBalances)
```

This prevents updating balances that haven't changed.

> 2. This correctly handles cases where a customer has more than one matching row in the @CustomerBalances table, right?

Yes. Because you use SUM() to aggregate them.

> 3. Is the EXISTS clause needed here?

It's recommended rather than essential. It's good practice so that you only attempt to update balances when records have been archived.

> 4. Will SUM() return 0 or NULL if there are no matching rows?

Yes, this is a bug that will cause balances to be set to NULL (or error if NULL not allowed) for customers who had no transactions archived. This will be fixed by adding the WHERE clause noted above. If you're trying to avoid the WHERE for some reason you can fix it with COALESCE(SUM(Amount),0.00)

> 5. Does everything get cleaned up if I don't have the final DELETE statement?

Yes. When the procedure completes, the table variable will go out of scope automatically, so the DELETE isn't need, as far as this snippet shows.

> 6. It is critical that no changes are made to the Transactions or Customers table while I'm doing this. Does my use of TABLOCK make sense here?

Yes, but you should also specify HOLDLOCK to keep the lock until the transaction completes.

> 7. Any suggestions about the overall approach I'm taking?

See above, but in general it looks to be reasonable.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to address all the questions. In particular, I'm not at all familiar with `HOLDLOCK`. Going over them carefully now!